# Let G be a group of order 6. Then either G is cyclic, or it is isomorphic to S3

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've been attempting to understand my professor's proof for the above statement which goes as follows:

**Proof**

Cauchy’s theorem implies that there exist elements $g, h ∈ G$ of order 3,2 respectively.

Theorem 3.18 implies that the subgroup $N$ = $\langle g\rangle$ is normal in G, so that
$hgh^{-1}$ = $g^i$
for some $i$ ∈ {0, 1, 2}.

Since the map N $→$ N, $g^n$ $→$ $hg^nh^{−1}$ has
an inverse, namely conjugation by $h^{-1}$
(which happens to be equal to h, but
that doesn’t matter here), there are, in fact, only two possibilities for i:

Either
$hgh^{−1}$ = g or $hgh^{−1}$ = $g^2$ = $g^{−1}$
. The first of these implies that G is cyclic,
generated by gh, while the second implies that G $\cong$ S3, where g corresponds to
a 3-cyclic, and h corresponds to a 2-cycle.

For reference the theorem utilized here states:

Let G be a finite group, let p be the smallest prime divisor of
#G, and let H ≤ G be a subgroup of index p. Then H is normal in G.

The problem I have so far is deciphering how he has used the theorem to conclude that the cyclic group of order 3 is normal when 3 isn't the smallest prime divisor. Is there something I am missing or is this an error on his behalf?

Edit: I am now aware of the previous error I made. Struggling to see how the mappings imply either a cyclic group or isomorphism with S3.

Comment: If $N$ is the cyclic subgroup of order $3,$ then $$|G/N|=2,$$ so $N$ is normal.

Comment: He used the theorem with $p=2$. Are you confusing order and index?

Comment: @SeanEberhard Yeah that makes sense now. I don't know why I was thinking in terms of the order. Thanks